# Assigning bool value to address of variable

Tags: pointers, reference, boolean

I'm playing around with references, pointers and values in c++17. While studying the topic I came across this event and I don't understand how it works.

```
bool fact = true;
bool *ptr = &fact;
std::cout << ptr;
```

prints the address of fact as expected.

If I try to assign the address of **fact** to a regular bool type and not a pointer, it prints **1** on the console:

```
bool fact = true;
bool ptr = &fact;
```

My question is why don't I get a compiler error? Aren't addresses of variables always supposed to be passed on pointers? Can I assing the address of a variable in a string type?

Doing the same test with different types results in compiling errors (as would be expected), eg:

```
int num = 10;
int ptr = &num;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, pointers are [implicitly converted](https://abseil.io/tips/141) to `bool` when a `bool` is required.

This is mainly meant to allow this code:

```
int *p = &my_param;
if (p != nullptr) {
    ...
}
```

to be simplified as:

```
int *p = &my_param;
if (p) {
    ...
}
```

But your variable `ptr` is `bool` and you're initializing it with a pointer, so C++ converts it because it sees a `bool` is required.

The convertion rule, as you can see from the example, is `false` if `pointer == nullptr` and `true` if `pointer != nullptr`.

The reason you're getting `1` in the output is that `cout` doesn't know how to print booleans, it just prints them as `int`s.

C++ pointers are not as useful when converted to `int` as they are when converted to `bool`, so there's no implicit `int` conversion, which is why you're getting compile errors with `int` instead of `bool`.